# Prove or Disprove That Orthogonal Matrices Commute with Skew-Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

Let $R$ be a real orthogonal matrix,
$$RR^T = I$$
and let $\Omega$ be a real skew-symmetric matrix,
$$\Omega^T = -\Omega$$

Please show or disprove that,
$$ R \Omega = \Omega R$$

I.e. prove whether or not orthogonal matrices and skew-symmetric matrices always commute in multiplication.

Is it possible to show using only the *defining* properties I listed? Or perhaps it might be necessary to also use the fact that skew-symmetric matrices commute with their transposes.

Comment: Quick lemma for skew-symmetric matrices commute with their transposes: just left and right multiply the skew-symmetric definition by $\Omega$.
$$\Omega^T := -\Omega$$
$$\Omega \Omega^T = -\Omega \Omega$$
$$\Omega^T \Omega = -\Omega \Omega$$
$$\therefore\ \  \Omega \Omega^T = \Omega^T \Omega$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false. Consider
$$ \Omega=\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      0&1&0\\
      -1&0&0\\
      0&0&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$
and
$$ R=\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      1&0&0\\
      0&0&1\\
      0&1&0
    \end{array}
\right].$$

What you may have tried are the two by two matrices, which the commutativity holds except possibly when the orthogonal matrix has determinant $-1$.